# Celery can't find user module

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery for for an app that downloads data. The directory structure is:

```
proj
    __init__.py
    celeryApp.py
    tasks.py
    startup.py
    fetcher.py
```

I run celery with `celery worker --app=celeryApp:app -l info` from inside the proj folder.

I run my app which queues tasks by running: `python startup.py`. Both `startup.py` and `fetcher.py` import `tasks.py`. In `startup.py` I create an object of a class `Fetcher` defined in `fetcher.py` and pass that as an argument to a task `runFetcher` in `tasks.py`.

This results in an error

> DecodeError: No module named fetcher

What changes would I need to make, so that I can safely pass such an object to a task?

Update: I added `import fetcher` to `tasks.py` which was fine to do as these tasks were closely related to the fetcher. Can anyone suggest a solution which does not require importing fetcher in tasks?

Comment: can you update your answer with code snippets from each file - just the import statements from `startup.py`, `fetcher.py` - this will make it much easier to understand what is going on

Comment: The DecodeError is unusual - can you provide the full traceback?